# Can't restore the original behavior from the decompiled simple app

Tags: gcc, x86, nasm, reverse-engineering, disassembly

I have started learning the NASM assembler & RE. The first problem I've got is the next (in short):

*I can't restore the decompiled program using the* `objconv` *utility*.

My simple app:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* msg = "Hello World!";

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\r\n", msg);
    return 0;
}
```

1). The first step, I've done was:

```
gcc -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -s -c -o 1.o 1.c
```

The flag: `fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` was used for NOT generating the unnecessary sections in the output object file.

2). Then, I've used the `objconv` utility in such way:

```
objconv -fnasm 1.o
```

for generating the assembly code for the `NASM` assembler, I've got the next:

```
; Disassembly of file: 1.o
; Sun Aug 27 23:56:53 2017
; Mode: 64 bits
; Syntax: YASM/NASM
; Instruction set: 8086, x64

default rel

global main: function
global msg

extern printf                                           ; near


SECTION .text   align=1 execute                         ; section number 1, code

main:   ; Function begin
        push    rbp                                     ; 0000 _ 55
        mov     rbp, rsp                                ; 0001 _ 48: 89. E5
        mov     rax, qword [rel msg]                    ; 0004 _ 48: 8B. 05, 00000000(rel)
        mov     rsi, rax                                ; 000B _ 48: 89. C6
        mov     edi, ?_001                              ; 000E _ BF, 00000000(d)
        mov     eax, 0                                  ; 0013 _ B8, 00000000
        call    printf                                  ; 0018 _ E8, 00000000(rel)
        mov     eax, 0                                  ; 001D _ B8, 00000000
        pop     rbp                                     ; 0022 _ 5D
        ret                                             ; 0023 _ C3
; main End of function


SECTION .data   align=8 noexecute                       ; section number 2, data

msg:                                                    ; qword
        dq Unnamed_4_0                                  ; 0000 _ 0000000000000000 (d)


SECTION .bss    align=1 noexecute                       ; section number 3, bss


SECTION .rodata align=1 noexecute                       ; section number 4, const

        db 48H, 65H, 6CH, 6CH, 6FH, 20H, 57H, 6FH       ; 0000 _ Hello Wo
        db 72H, 6CH, 64H, 21H, 00H                      ; 0008 _ rld!.

?_001:                                                  ; byte
        db 25H, 73H, 0DH, 0AH, 00H                      ; 000D _ %s...
```

3). The next step was in:

Removing the unnecessary parts like:

- the **align=N** and **execute/noexecute** words from the `.SECTION` lines
- `: function` from the **global** declaration
- the `default rel` line

Fixing the `msg: dq Unnamed_4_0`. I have thought, that this part is rather compromised/broken after using the `objconv`.

So, I've change the:

```
dq Unnamed_4_0
```

To the:

```
db "Hello World",10
```

Despite on having the section: `.rodata` (I'm thinking, that my problem was exactly with the incorrect using of the string for output...).

4). Then I have used the next commands in shell:

```
nasm -f elf64 1.asm
gcc 1.o
```

When, I'm launching the `a.out` file after gcc, I've got the next error:

```
user@:~/Desktop/tmp$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is how I have failed to restore the original behavior from the disassembled program. The original program was compiled via:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o 1 1.c
```

The source code of it was published at the beginning of my question. The aim I want to achieve is simple: to build the executable from using the `objconv -> nasm` approach, which acts as the original executable.

Comment: You're disassembling, not decompiling.  This is not safe in general, because NASM syntax can't represent different instruction-encoding choices that might e.g. leave necessary padding in the PLT.  If you're just keeping the disassembled `main`, then that should be ok.  Probably you broke something, and you should use `gdb ./a.out` to find out what.  (See the gdb for asm tips at the bottom of [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).)

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the good & constructive answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `char* msg = "Hello World!";`, so you have a pointer to a string literal stored in the read/write `.data` section.  That's the `dq Unnamed_4_0`.

If you had written `char msg[] = "Hello World!";`, the bytes at `msg` would be the literal string, and `main` would pass a pointer to `printf` with `mov edi, msg` (i.e. `mov r32,imm32`).

You changed the asm so the bytes at `msg:` are string data rather than a pointer.  But your `main` is still passing the first 8 bytes stored at `msg` to `printf` as a *pointer* (as the `const char *fmt` arg).

When `printf` tries to dereference those ASCII bytes as a pointer to the format string, it segfaults.  (Remember that in C, strings are passed by reference.)

---

BTW, I'd suggest compiling with `gcc -Og` or `-O1` at least.  It will be a lot easier to read the asm when it isn't storing/reloading everything to the stack after every C statement (to let you change any variable with a debugger).  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for more tips.